# IdentityResult to ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there an easy way to convert an `IdentityResult` to an `IActionResult` taking into account errors?

Comment: they are completely unrelated concepts, just because they both have the word Result in them doesn't mean they are convertible from one to another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IdentityResult` is just a class which tells you if an ASP.NET (Core) Identity operation succeeded or not and in case of an error offers you error messages and is unrelated to MVC Action's results which implement `IActionResult` interface.

If you use WebApi/RestApi controllers , you'd translate it to something like

```cs
public IActionResult SomeActionName() 
{
    IdentityResult result = ...; // some identity operation

    // all is okay, return http code 200
    if(result.Success) 
        return Ok();

    // error happened, return http code 400 + errors as json
    return BadRequest(result.Errors);
}
```

Or if you are **really lazy**, write your own `IActionResult`:

```cs
public class IdentityActionResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly IdentityResult identityResult;

    public IdentityActionResult(IdentityResult identityResult) 
    {
        this.identityResult = identityResult;
    }

    public Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        IActionResult actionResult = null;
        if(identityResult.Success)
        {
            actionResult = new OkResult();
        }
        else
        {
            actionResult = new BadRequestObjectResult(identityResult.Errors);
        }

        return actionResult.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

Of course this can be further optimized so that you don't have to create two `IActionResult` objects per request, but that's an exercise left up to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method for `IdentityResult` which returns ObjectResult something like this:

```
public static class IdentityResultExtension
{
    public static ObjectResult ToObjectResult(this IdentityResult result)
    {
        // 
        return new ObjectResult(result);
    }
}
```

then use it in action:

```
public IActionResult YourAction() 
{
    IdentityResult result;
    return result.ToObjectResult();
}
```